# How can I print two specified columns of a table?

Tags: python

when I execute

```
import akshare as ak

# Fetch all stock prices
stock_prices = ak.stock_zh_a_spot()
print(stock_prices)
```

I get a table which looks like

```
代码    名称    最新价   涨跌额    涨跌幅     买入     卖出     昨收     今开     最高  \
0     bj430017  星昊医药   9.96 -0.11 -1.092   9.96   9.97  10.07  10.08  10.10   
1     bj430047  诺思兰德  15.20  0.22  1.469  15.20  15.21  14.98  15.46  16.16   
2     bj430090  同辉信息   2.65  0.01  0.379   2.64   2.65   2.64   2.68   2.68   
3     bj430139  华岭股份  10.82  0.31  2.950  10.76  10.82  10.51  10.48
```

How can I print two specified columns, which are 名称 and 最新价?
I use

```
for code, price in stock_prices.items():
    print(f"股票代码：{code}，最新价格：{price['最新价']}")
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: `stock_prices[["最新价"]]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

it's a DataFrame, you can access the column directly using the column name and then iterate through the items in that column.

```
for price in stock_prices['最新价']:
    print(price)
```

Comment: What if I want to print 名称 and 最新价?

Comment: u can use `zip` function to do that: `for name, price in zip(stock_prices['名称'], stock_prices['最新价']):
    print(name, price)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print just one column from the DataFrame, you can do it by calling that column's name directly. In pandas DataFrame, you can call a column by `df['column_name']`. Therefore, in your case, you can print the 最新价 column like this:

```
print(stock_prices['最新价'])
```

This will print out the entire 最新价 column from your DataFrame.

If you would like to iterate over the dataframe and print each stock code along with its price, you can use the `iterrows()` method in pandas:

```
for index, row in stock_prices.iterrows():
    print(f"股票代码：{row['代码']}，最新价格：{row['最新价']}")
```